# Can two programs, written in different languages, connect to the same SQL database?

Tags: sql, node.js, python-2.7

The question is pretty much in the header, but here are the specifics. For my senior design project we are going to be writing software to control some hardware and display diagnostics info on a web front. To accomplish this, I'm planning to use a combination of Python and nodejs. Theoretically, a python service script will communicate with the hardware via bacnet IP and log diagnostic info in an SQL database. The nodejs JavaScript server code will respond to webfront requests by querying the database and returning the relevant info. I'm pretty new to SQL, so my primary question is.. Is this possible? My second and more abstract questions would be... is this wise? And, is there any obvious advantage to using the same language on both ends, whether that language is Python, Java, or something else?

Comment: A minor point - you should not use the term _SQL database_, because this a misnomer. Most relational databases speak SQL, so there is no such "SQL database". A database would be Oracle, MSSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL, DB2 - (and all these support SQL) but there is no "SQL _database_". Its like saying there is a "Python database", just like Python, SQL is a _language_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

You can use any programming language that provides a client for the database server of your choice.

To the database server, as long as the client is communicating as per the server's requirements (that is, it is using the server's library, protocol, etc.), then there is no difference to what programming language or system is being used.

---

The database drivers provide a common abstract layer, providing a guarantee that the database server and the client are speaking the same language.

The programming language's interface to the database driver takes care of the language specifics - for example, providing syntax that conforms to the language; and on the opposite side it the driver will ensure that all commands are sent in the protocol that the server expects.

Since drivers are such a core requirement, there are usually multiple drivers available for databases; and also because good database access is a core requirement for programmers, each language strives to have a "standard" API for all databases. For example Java has JDBC
Python has the DB-API, .NET has ODBC (and ADO I believe, but I am not a .NET expert).

These are what the database drivers will conform to, so that it doesn't matter which database server you are using, you have one standard way to connect, one standard way to execute queries and one standard way to fetch results - in effect, making your life as a programmer easier.

In most cases, there is a reference driver (and API/library) provided by the database vendor. It is usually in C, and it is also what the "native" client to the database uses.  For example the `mysql` *client* for the MySQL database server using the MySQL C drivers to connect, and it is the same driver that is used by the Python MySQLdb driver; which conforms to the Python DB-API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.

Two applications with different languages using one database is almost exactly the same as one application using several connections to it, so you are probably already doing it. All the possible problems are exactly the same. The database won't even know whether the connections are made from one application or the other.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much possible and common practise. There may be parts where you have to write your applications around the data rather than vise versa but this is do-able.

If you are using much of the same query's in each application I would also recommend using [Stored Procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) where possible.